# Dúvida sobre a each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

No [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/8uk440do/18/) abaixo, é exibido a multiplicação do value do "checkbox" (se checked) pelo valor escolhido no "select" da mesma linha, há um "reset" do respectivo "select" ao desmarcar o "checkbox" e há um resultado em paralelo só da soma dos valores do select.

Esse código é resultado de perguntas anteriores (aulas) aqui do Stack, com as dicas consegui fazer funcionar perfeitamente.

A minha pergunta de iniciante, é se há redundância no código desta forma que fiz e se é possível fazer tudo com uma só each()?
Como podem ver, há duas "each()":

`$('tr').each(function(){ _código_ });` e `$('table input').each(function(){ _código_ });`.

Segue exemplo funcional para melhor entendimento: https://jsfiddle.net/8uk440do/18/

Desde já, obrigado por me auxiliarem no aprendizado.

Comment: Só alertando, faltou um `)` ai no código da pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado @DiegoF, fiz as correções.

Comment: DAnilo, ainda está faltando um parênteses: `$('tr').each(function())` e `$('table input').each(function(i))`

Comment: Obrigado @DiegoF, fiz as correções...

Comment: Danilo, o `each()` serve para interar uma coleção executando um determinado trecho de codigo, no seu exemplo, ambas as coleções são diferentes e o codigo executado também é diferente... então o codigo não possui redundancia... até daria para fazer com um unico `each()`, mas o codigo ficaria sujo e dificultaria o entendimento do mesmo.

Comment: Entendi @TobyMosque, obrigado. Na sua opinião, didaticamente falando, essa é a melhor maneira de se fazer isso?

Comment: Sim, acredito que seja.

Comment: @TobyMosque, Obrigado

Comment: @TobyMosque, bom dia. Basicamente o que altera para a utilização da metodologia each() em uma estrutura de "divs", sem estrutura de tabela, tr... ? Estou aqui tentando aplicar o ultimo aprendizado que vocês me passaram porem esbarrei nessa dificuldade